# SQL calculate the sum of a column based on the date in two differents variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a simple table in this forme :

```
BillItem (id,amount, volume, bill_date,....other fields)
```

I want to obtain in my query 4 differents sum of fields amount and volume based on the date

for example, in my table i've this data :

```
Id | amount | volume | bill_date | libelle
1  | 10     | 50     | 02/04/2016| bill1       
2  | 20     | 55     | 02/04/2016| bill1
2  | 88     | 66     | 02/05/2016| bill1
3  | 30     | 60     | 03/05/2016| bill2
4  | 40     | 10     | 02/04/2016| bill3
5  | 50     | 20     | 02/05/2016| bill3
```

and the result must be like this :

```
bill1, sum_date_1=30, sum_date_2=88, sum_volume_date_1=105, sum_volume_date_2=66
bill2, sum_date_1=0, sum_date_2=30, sum_volume_date_1=0, sum_volume_date_2=60
bill3, sum_date_1=40, sum_date_2=50, sum_volume_date_1=10, sum_volume_date_2=20
```

i've this query with only two sum variable :

```
select ans.SERVICE_TYPE, ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE,
sum(bi.ACTUAL_AMOUNTVAT),sum(bi.ACTUAL_VOLUME), bi.BILL_DATE 
from bill_item bi left outer join ANALYTIC_SECTION ans on ans.TREE_PATH=bi.REPORT_SECTION
where bi.account_id=7
and bi.BILL_DATE<='31/05/2016' and bi.BILL_DATE>='01/04/2016' 
and ans.REPORT_TYPE='ARPE_REPORT' and ans.ACCOUNT_ID=7
group by ans.SERVICE_TYPE, ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE, bi.BILL_DATE;
```

Is it possible to obtain two differents sum for each field (amount and volume) ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear on this question - What do you mean by two different sums for each field? What is the expected result?

Comment: The field here is 'libelle', two differents sum means for field 'libelle', i've 1 sum for first month and another sum for second month

Comment: Your query is perfect and of course you can sum up multiple columns.

Comment: but that is what the date difference will do..isn't it!

Comment: @Arif Sarker : in my query, i've add only one sum for each field. I want two sum for each field (different month)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : sql developer

Comment: That is not a DBMS, that is a SQL client tool which can connect to various database. But it is usually used for Oracle, so I guess assuming you are using Oracle is fine

Comment: Yes sorry, it's Oracle

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you want to summarize by each date and then return the value for the months in ascending fields?

It might work with a subquery and a ranking option, although this may not be the most efficient route.

```
    Select t.Id
     ,  Max(Case When t.BillRank=1 Then t.SumVolume Else Null End) As Volume1
     , Max(Case When t.BillRank=2 Then t.SumVolume Else Null End) As Volume2 
     , Max(Case When t.BillRank=1 Then t.SumVAT Else Null End) As Vat1 
     , Max(Case When t.BillRank=2 Then t.SumVAT Else Null End) As Vat2 
From    ( Select    ans.SERVICE_TYPE
                  , ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE
                  , Sum(bi.ACTUAL_AMOUNTVAT) As SumVAT
                  , Sum(bi.ACTUAL_VOLUME) As SumVolume 
                  , bi.BILL_DATE
                  , bi.Id
                  , Rank() Over ( Partition By bi.Id Order By bi.BILL_DATE Asc ) As BillRank
          From      bill_item As bi
                    Left Outer Join ANALYTIC_SECTION as ans
                        On ans.TREE_PATH = bi.REPORT_SECTION
          Group By  ans.SERVICE_TYPE
                  , ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE
                  , bi.BILL_DATE
                  , bi.Id
        ) t
Group By t.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris J for your help. when i try to execute query, i've this error : 

00936. 00000 -  "missing expression" behind Select [t].Id

Comment: @fay.doca can you try just running the subquery? and see if this runs? (the bit in the parentheses) - I've also corrected a few small issues with aliases which might help.

Comment: i've trying also to execute sub query, i've this error : 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: `Volume1 = ...` is invalid standard SQL (and so are the square brackets `[` and `]` as part of an identifier). The question is tagged only with `sql` to answers should use standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, will make changes - my tsql is showing!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the query like this :

```
select distinct ans.SERVICE_TYPE, ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE,
sum(Case when bi.BILL_DATE<'01/05/2016' then bi.ACTUAL_AMOUNTVAT ELSE 0 END) as amount_m1,
sum(Case when bi.BILL_DATE>='01/05/2016' then bi.ACTUAL_AMOUNTVAT ELSE 0 END) as amount_m,
sum(Case when bi.BILL_DATE<'01/05/2016' then bi.ACTUAL_VOLUME ELSE 0 END) as volume_m1,
sum(Case when bi.BILL_DATE>='01/05/2016' then bi.ACTUAL_VOLUME ELSE 0 END) as volume_m
--,bi.BILL_DATE 
from bill_item bi left outer join ANALYTIC_SECTION ans on ans.TREE_PATH=bi.REPORT_SECTION
where bi.account_id=7
and bi.BILL_DATE<='06/05/2016' and bi.BILL_DATE>='06/04/2016' 
and ans.REPORT_TYPE='ARPE_REPORT' and ans.ACCOUNT_ID=7
group by ans.SERVICE_TYPE, ans.SERVICE_SUB_TYPE;
```

Thank's All for your help